# Get C/CXX FLAGS set by commands add_definitions() and add_compile_options()

Tags: cmake, configure, cc, ldflags, cflags

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, global C and CXX flags are set using commands [add_definitions()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions)
and
[add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html).

Many attempts to retrieve the C/CXX flags:

1. `${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}` and `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` are empty
2. `${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}}` is the original default CMake value
   (e.g. `-g` for `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG`)
3. `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}}` same as above
4. `get_cmake_property(def COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)` is `NOTFOUND`
5. `get_cmake_property(opt COMPILE_OPTIONS)` is also `NOTFOUND`

I want to pass my custom C/CXX flags to an external project based on `./configure`:

```
ExternalProject_Add( my_external_lib
  DEPENDS            Threads::Threads
  SOURCE_DIR         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE    1
  UPDATE_COMMAND     echo "Full clean" && make distclean
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/configure
       --prefix=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
       --cc=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
       --cxx=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
       --CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}}
       --CXXFLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}}
       --LDFLAGS=${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}}
       --ARFLAGS=${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}}
       --enable-static
)
```

(1) **How to get compilation flags set by [add_definitions()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions) and [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html)?**

Note: I use CMake version 3.3.2

---

<sub>While writing the question, I realize I am wondering another question:</sub>

I use `ccache` but the `./configure` script does not see my environment variables `CC` and `CXX` when I set them like that:

```
get_cmake_property(launcher   RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE)
set(ENV{CC}  ${launcher} ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(ENV{CXX} ${launcher} ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
```

(2) **Are these above CMake statements correct?**

---

<sub>Oops I have again another question:</sub>

I retrieve the `LDFLAGS` and `ARFLAGS` from the same variable `${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS}`.
(3) **Is there another CMake variable to set `ARFLAGS`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several questions in one post, but all of them are simple:

1. Documentation link for `add_definitions()` explicitely refers to [directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_OPTIONS) and [target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_OPTIONS) COMPILE_DEFINITION properties. The first of them is extracted by using [get_directory_property()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_directory_property.html), the second by using [get_target_property()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_target_property.html). Any of them can also be extracted by using [get_property()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_property.html). `get_cmake_property` you tried to use is inapplicable here (it is used for other type of properties).
2. You set environment variables CC and CXX at *configuration* step, but all commands for `ExternalProject_Add` are executed at *build* step.

Currently `ExternalProject_Add` doesn't support simple setting environment variables. As adviced in [this bugreport](https://cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=5145), for set variable's value *without spaces* you may prepend command with "VAR=VAL" clauses. But for your case this wouldn't work because of escaping problems.

See also CMake FAQ: [**How can I get or set environment variables?**](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/index.php?title=CMake_FAQ&redirect=no#How_can_I_get_or_set_environment_variables.3F)

> [...]
>   environment variables `SET` in the CMakeLists.txt *only*
>   take effect for cmake itself (*configure-time*),
>   so you cannot use this method to set an environment variable
>   that a custom command might need (*build-time*). 
>   Barring environment variable support by various CMake commands
>   (e.g. `add_custom_command()`, currently not supported yet),
>   an acceptable workaround may be to invoke shell scripts instead
>   which wrap the commands to be executed.

Simple *wrapper* script to set environment variables and run actual command:

**wrapper.sh.in**:

```
export "CC=ccache @CMAKE_C_COMPILER@"
export "CXX=ccache @CMAKE_XX_COMPILER@"
eval "$*"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
configure_file(wrapper.sh.in wrapper.sh @ONLY)
ExternalProject_Add(my_external_lib
    ...
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND /bin/sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper.sh
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/configure ...
    BUILD_COMMAND /bin/sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/wrapper.sh make
)
```

Note, that you should use wrapper for every command which requires this variables. In you case, these are CONFIGURE_COMMAND and BUILD_COMMAND.

3. [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS.html) for CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS says that these flags are used for linker, so you may probably use them as LDFLAGS. As for ARFLAGS, they are hardcoded directrly to [CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_ARCHIVE_CREATE.html) variable, contained full command line for `ar`. By default this command simply uses linker flags, so your approach seems to be correct too.